# VBA For loop to copy cells from excel to word

Tags: vba, loops, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to create an excel macro to copy cells from excel to word. I need to take it from sheet 1 in excel to table 1 in word.

I need to do this via a loop (as I have to perform operations on the cells etc.) and I can't work out how to do it.
I have the following code:

```
Sub test()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim FileName As String
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer

'Open Word file
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Template.doc"
Set wdApp = New Word.Application
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName)



' Loop through columns and rows
For iCol = 1 To 3 ' or however many columns you have
    For iRow = 1 To 2

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, iCol)
        ' Copy the cell to the destination
        .Copy
        wdDoc.Selection.Paste
    End With

    Next iRow
Next iCol

End Sub
```

When I run this though, the line **wdDoc.Selection.Paste** gives the error:

> Run-time error '438': Object does not support this property or method.

I'm also aware that this doesn't paste into table 1 of the document, but right now it doesn't do *anything*, so I thought I'd work on that first.
I'm new to VBA but have other programming experience. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
wdApp.Selection.Range.Paste
```

**EDIT**: more complete example

```
Sub test()

Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, wdApp As Word.Application
Dim tbl As Word.Table


Dim FileName As String
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer


    FileName = "C:\_stuff\Local Files\temp.docx"
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application

    wdApp.Visible = True 'add this to see the Word instance and document

    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(FileName)

    Set tbl = wdDoc.Tables(1)

    ' Loop through columns and rows
    For iRow = 1 To 2
    For iCol = 1 To 3 ' or however many columns you have
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, iCol)
            tbl.Rows(iRow).Cells(iCol).Range.Text = .Value
        End With
    Next iCol
    Next iRow


    wdDoc.Close False  ' close doc and save changes
    wdApp.Quit        'close word (will auto-close if no open documents)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim. Still doesn't work though. Comes up with the same error.
Each time I try, it notifies me that the document is locked for editing (by me) so I "open a local copy". Not sure if this makes a difference or not.

Comment: Are you closing the document at the end of your macro?  you're not making the Word instance visible `wdApp.Visible = True` so it will not be obvious if Word is still open (you may have multiple instances open).  Have a look in Task Manager and see what's there.

Comment: Yeah I checked TM and found a few in there and have since added a statement to close word.
Still not copying though. Maybe I need to declare it as a word range or something?

Comment: See my update - inserting text directly is preferrable to copy/paste

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you sir!
Solves my _current_ problem ;)

Comment: Have accepted the answer. Sorry I can't upvote though, I don't have enough rep.